# Check who a user has permission to send on behalf of?

Tags: docusignapi

For a DocuSign integration, I'm working on allowing users to send on behalf of others. Using DocuSign's REST API, I am able to send on behalf of another DocuSign user by using the `<SendOnBehalfOf>` node inside the `X-DocuSign-Authentication` header of the request, as described [here](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm?utm_campaign=DevCenter%20Nurture%20Campaign%20Email%201%20-%20Key%20Information&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Eloqua#SOBO/Send%20On%20Behalf%20Of%20Functionality%20in%20the%20DocuSign%20REST%20API.htm%3FTocPath%3D_____3).

I've also found that to find any DocuSign users capable of sending on behalf of, I just need to check their `apiAccountWideAccess` and `allowSendOnBehalfOf` permissions.

This alone seems like a security concern for me. Is there a way for me to, first in DocuSign, restrict users for designated sending? For example, can I make it so John can send on behalf of Bob, but Jane cannot? If possible, can I then use the DocuSign REST API to check *who* a particular user *can* send on behalf of?

Or, does DocuSign allow **any** designated sender to send on behalf of **any** other user, so long as they have the aforementioned permissions? I can't find any documentation about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Group called "DocuSign Viewer" that will restrict users from sending envelopes. You can assign the a new user to that group by using the group ID when making the call to create the user (or do it in the member console easily as well).

As far as sending on behalf of, the initiating sender will need Account Wide Rights (apiAccountWideAccess in the API). The only restriction for the user they are sending for is they must be able to send envelopes.